# Force current state of Git branch on another branch

Tags: git

Let's say I have a Git repo with two branches: #branch1 and #branch2.

They both have had commits since they branched out from the same source.

It turned out that changes in #branch1 are not needed. I want to force current state of #branch2 1:1 onto #branch1.

I don't want to do regular branch merge, because I know that no changes made onto #branch1 are needed and I don't want to deal with conflicts and allow any chance that some of those changes are carried over.

What's the best git operation would be in this case?

P.S. I'm using GitExtensions, but could go with command-line git as well if necessary. The repo is also hosted on BeanStalk.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out branch 1 and then do `git reset --hard commitOfBranch2` where `commitOfBranch2` is the commit that branch 2 is pointing to.

You can do this with GitExtensions too.

Comment: OK, now I have another problem. The branch would now not push to remote repo (hosted BeanStalk). "remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/branch1 (you should pull first)" Is there any way to force current state of the local branch onto the remote repo?

Comment: Nevermind, BT has a repo setting which enables non-fastforward commits. Worked nicely. Thanks and sorry for the stupid followups.